# How to find a document in a document library using jquery

Tags: document-library, jquery

I have a requirement to check for duplicate documents in the document library. How can i implement this using jquery. Please share the code.

Comment: why would you do that? what is duplicate document? Did you read the [ask] page? Did you visit http://whathaveyoutried.com ?

Comment: i have a requirement where in i was uploading a document into a doc lib using custom code. So whenever i do that i wanted to check if the user is uploading a unique doc.

Comment: Unique in what way? Filename? Contents (I suppose creating a hash and comparing it to the hash of files in the library)?

Answer (score 2):

Code to check if the document exists in the doc lib using jquery

```
function findDocument(fileName, docLibName) {
        var optValue = "0";
        var query = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><Value Type='File'>" + fileName + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>";

        $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetListItems",
            listName: docLibName,
            CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID' /></ViewFields>",
            CAMLQuery: query,
            async: false,

            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                    optValue = $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("rs:data").attr("ItemCount");
            }
        });
        return optValue;
    }
```

Comment: You'll need to fix the formatting of your answer as right now it looks like this returns the number of documents in a library because you're missing a some spaces in the markdown. (When I edit the post I see you're performing a query based on a supplied file name, and I can't save my edit of four spaces).

Comment: yes, i am returning the count. So i check that if the count is more than 0, that implies that the document exists.